# "Вылетает" мое приложение установленное из Googl play. Почему?

Tags: java, android

Я разработчик (любитель). Выложил (обновил) приложение в Googl play (API 24-29, app-release.apk). Приложение устанавливается, но при нажатии на любую клавишу - "слетает". Слетает и не только у меня, выборочно (от модели телефона не зависит). **Но, тот же файл apk,** который выкладывал в Googl play, перенес в свой телефон, установил и все работает отлично. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Ты в коде делал защиту от пересборки apk?

Comment: Логи смотреть не пробовали? - говорят помогает найти причину ;).

Comment: попробуйте установить из маркета приложение, открыть в студии проект и запустить приложение, по логике вы увидите логи в которых будет краш. Так же я бы советовал посмотреть в сторону FireBase Crashlytics сервиса который поможет в отлове падений без необходимости подключения устройства к ПК

Comment: -  Arty Morris.  Нет не делал.

Comment: – Andrew. Буду пробовать. ДА, ЭТОТ ВАРИАНТ НАГЛЯДНЕЕ. СПАСИБО. Куда тут like ставить?

Comment: – woesss. Логи я смотрел на эмуляторе. И после установки на телефон проверял работоспособность, все было нормально. Но вот если установить с googl play... вот тут начинаются проблемы. С таким сталкиваюсь впервые. Спасибо  Andrew - пролил свет на проблему.

Comment: Скорее всего у вас проблемы с подписью приложения. Скорее всего вы согласились на подпись гуглом (что очень плохо и необратимо) и надо всякие сервисы теперь настраивать на подпись гугла, а не вашу. Сами вы теперь не сможете локально собрать APK аналогичное тому, которое в магазине.

Comment: – ЮрийСПб. Да, недавно было предложение вроде хранения ключей (может это и есть подпись гуглом), я согласился (уж очень часто появлялось это сообщение). Я разработчик (любитель-аматор) - это не мое призвание. Просто хотелось сделать несколько церковных приложений. В логах нашел несколько ошибок после подключения телефона к ПК. Но не пойму откуда они взялись. Попробую исправить. А как быть в будущем?